# Job Queue Not Wokring Laravel on Server

Tags: laravel, server, queue, jobs

i have issue in job queue not working on my server but in my local system it working perfect.
but not work in my server.
but on my server in jobs when i send mail then new entry enter in jobs table but it not attempt on server so it not send mail from jobs table .

Comment: did you run the queue on your server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many tries I have found solution with my server that is below setting working fine :

.env file setup MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail.

config/mail.php file 'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -t' replace -bs with -t.